# No results from a query with Date type in SQLite - Java/Android

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I perform the following query in a SQLite database:

```
" ...WHERE mydate >= '" + inicialdate + "' AND mydate <= '" + finaldate + "'";
```

`mydate` is the field in the DataBase, type DATE. `inicialdate` and `finaldate` are Strings.

The idea here is to perform a query between two different dates given by the user.
I use a DataPicker to allow the user input the data.
So, I get these dates returned from the DatePicker and put them in the `inicialdate` and `finaldate` Strings.

The format of the date I'm putting in the Strings is "YYYY-MM-DD".

The query returns something when I just put some value in the `finaldate` String, but when i put dates in the two Strings, or just in the first one, I receive nothing from the query.

Comment: While the [`DATE` type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname) in SQLite is actually a numeric value, SQLite uses type affinity so it doesn't matter. What you are describing should work, could you provide an runnable example where the query fails?

Comment: Let's say:I have the data 2012-09-09 in my DB. So I want to find it by a query. So I tried to put the following values: inicialdate = 2012-09-08 and finaldate = 2012-09-10. It just don't works. But when I leave the inicialdate blank and I put in finaldate = 2012-09-10. I works for some reason.

Comment: I removed my "answer" because it was only a suggestion too detailed for comments, but my offer still stands, let me know if you need more help and can provide specific information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Sam. I finnaly find out the problem. I edited the question and there is the solution for the problem. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`" ...WHERE mydate >= '" + inicialdate + "' AND mydate <= '" + finaldate + "'";`

This piece of query is right. The problem was in my code, with de datapicker.

To perform a query in SQLITE I need to use the format YYYY-MM-DD. 
I was taking the data to perform a query directly from a datapicker, so sometimes it retrieves a data in the format YYYY-M-D. In a datapicker, when a month or day is lower than 10, it just put a single digit to represent the month or day.

Tha solution is just use an if statement to see if the number is lower than 10, then put a "0" before the number of the month or the day.

Well, this solved the problem at all

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
> sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test(mydate date);
sqlite> insert into test values('2012-09-09');
sqlite> select * from test where mydate >= '2012-09-08' and mydate <= '2012-09-10';
2012-09-09
```

Does the same query work in your DB?
I'd guess that the values in the table might use a different format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, CL. I finnaly find out the problem. Your query functions pretty well in my code. I edited the question and there is the solution for the problem. Thanks a lot again!